# Acer Aspire S7 wireless mouse not working, already replaced battery

Tags: mouse

I only use this mouse when I am travelling, I have another logitec mouse, that is for home use.
Last week the house mouse was not showing  cursor, it was about a half hour to fix.

This week, the mouse did not communicate at all with my laptop.

It is turned on, and even though I replaced the battery recently, I just replaced it again.  Nothing is changed.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, if you replace a depleted battery with a depleted battery, it isn't useful.
The problem (at least I think) is this:

Linux have problems with Windows driver. So, that device might had came with Windows driver. Try plugging in the mouse into a computer running windows, and see in the "Device manager" if it is "Installing device driver software". Although I have no idea how to fix this except using "WINE", this is what I imagined would be what happened. Next time, buy devices with the Tux penguin on the packaging.